# How to give an alias to an unnested array of tuples?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to set up a set of data using this query :

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([("a",NULL),("b",NULL),("c",1),("d",1),("e",2),("f",3),("g",4),("h",4),("i",4),("j",4),("k",5),("l",5),("m",6),("n",7),("o",7)]) 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

The yielded result is :

```
|Row|f0_|f1_ |
|---|---|----|
| 1 | a |null|
| 2 | b |null|
| 3 | c |1   |
| 4 | d |1   |
| 5 | e |2   |
| 6 | f |3   |
| 7 | g |4   |
| 8 | h |4   |
| 9 | i |4   |
| 10| j |4   |
| 11| k |5   |
| 12| l |5   |
| 13| m |6   |
| 14| n |7   |
| 15| o |7   |
```

What I want is :

```
|Row| x | y  |
|---|---|----|
| 1 | a |null|
| 2 | b |null|
| 3 | c |1   |
| 4 | d |1   |
| 5 | e |2   |
| 6 | f |3   |
| 7 | g |4   |
| 8 | h |4   |
| 9 | i |4   |
| 10| j |4   |
| 11| k |5   |
| 12| l |5   |
| 13| m |6   |
| 14| n |7   |
| 15| o |7   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `STRUCT`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([STRUCT("a" as x,NULL as y),("b",NULL),("c",1),("d",1),("e",2),("f",3),("g",4),("h",4),("i",4),("j",4),("k",5),("l",5),("m",6),("n",7),("o",7)]) 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

[image]

Comment: When I remove the `y` column from the struct to form a single-column table, then I'm getting *"Array elements of types {STRING, STRUCT<x STRING>} do not have a common supertype"*. Can that still be resolved with your approach, short of repeating the `STRUCT` keyword on every value?

Comment: We have to repeat STRUCT for every value if we have a single-valued struct. But in that case we can use just an array without struct instead: `SELECT * FROM UNNEST(["a","b"]) as x`

Comment: Ah yes, of course. The table name is taken for the column name as well, in that case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this trick with almost any SQL dialect:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT NULL AS A, NULL AS B
  FROM (SELECT 1) T
  WHERE FALSE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST([
    ("a",NULL),("b",NULL),("c",1),("d",1),("e",2),("f",3),
    ("g",4),("h",4),("i",4),("j",4),("k",5),("l",5),("m",6),("n",7),("o",7)
  ]) 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: It would be great to provide an explanation for this trick.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto: What's there to explain? Here's a prose version of the code: The first `UNION ALL` subquery provides aliases but no data, the second one provides the data?

Comment: `WHERE FALSE`? and `SELECT 1` were used just to fill the necessary SQL syntax? In short, what I mean is: it would be great for someone with less knowledge in SQL to understand this trick (and maybe adapt some part when necessary)

Comment: @FelipeAugusto: See, you deduced the meaning of the dummy `FROM` clause yourself, it didn't need a comment :) Cheers!